# How to create multiple delays using a dispatch queue?

Tags: swift

Is it possible to use DispatchQueue to create multiple delays in my code?

For example, with sleep I can do:

```
            for index in 1...20 {
                do {
                    sleep(1)
                    // Code I want to run every 1 second for 20 times
   
                }
            }
            completionHandler()
```

But I want to use DispatchQueue instead:

```
            for index in 1...20 {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                    // Code I want to run every 1 second for 20 times
  
                }
            }
            completionHandler()
```

which doesn't seem to be working (it's not waiting 1 second each time)

Edit:
At the end of running the code for 20 times, I want to call the completionHandler to return a result of the code in the loop. Problem is that this does not wait for the DispatchQueue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Code I want to run every 1 second for 20 times
```

What you're looking for is a Timer.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer

```
var timer : Timer?
var times = 0
@objc func fired(_ t:Timer) {
    times += 1
    print("do your code") // do your code here
    if times == 20 {
        t.invalidate()
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,
            selector: #selector(fired), userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true)
}
```

You will see that `print("do your code")` runs every 1 second 20 times.

Comment: Interesting, could I also use this with a completionHandler? I edited my question

Comment: Why not? Store the completion handler and call it at the point where I say `t.invalidate()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a different delay `Double(index)`

```
for index in 1...20 {
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(index)) {
     // Code I want to run every 1 second for 20 times
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me (it doesn't wait the 1 second if I put Double(1))